# Polls as adverts

Tags: discussion, advertising

The SE sites are quite large and can seem to offer a reasonably wide variety of people within each site. I'm not entirely sure if it costs to have ads on here? But could there be interactive polls in someof these ads. If the ads here must be paid for then couldn't these polls be used as Market research otherwise ot just be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sites' advertising info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact).